# Running Multiple Single Page Applications Under One Parent Application

Tags: angular, single-page-application

This may be a wild question.

My problem is this. We have multiple single page applications that service different parts of our customers businesses. E.g.

- Application A - an Angular SPA on one URL
- Application B - an Angular SPA on another URL

We would like to have a unified experience for our users so that they don't know whether they are jumping from one application to another.

- they could launch application B via a link presented in application A WITHOUT the SPA reloading again!

I am wondering if there is way that two SPA apps can be loaded into a container app so that this sort of cross application interaction is possible

Comment: Why not simply merge your two applications into a third, pristine one ?

Comment: This could be an internal platform with a broad range of functionalities to be presented to employers, so splitting a giant spa into smaller ones isn't a bad idea after all, it is somehow similar to a monolithic application vs microservices.

Answer (score 0):

To answer your question: No. There is no way to do that without merging the two applications into one. The problem will always be that the source code of either application A or B is not yet loaded. It will only be served to the user when they access the respective URL.

About running two angular apps under the same URL in general: It's possible, but not recommended for single page applications (SPAs).

Answer (score 0):

Mine is not an actual solution, but rather a though.

I too am investigating this topic (multiple spa served/masked as one), and I've notices that:

- Digital Ocean apps lets you build an app on top of multiple components
- AWS Cloudfront distributions lets you use multiple origins, like different buckets or a single bucket but different folders

This gives you the possibility to serve/present different single page applications under the same url, but you have to take are of the session data being passed/synced across those, like stores in vue applications.
You could use some package to persist them in the browser storage and load/update when loading a different spa, maybe using a 'last updated' timestamp to check if overwrite the in-store data with the one from the browser storage or not.

Of course this approach lead to smaller 'chunks' for your application, with the consequent ease of development and maintenance and a more focused scope of each, but also brings the complexity of sharing consistent session data structures, layouts, permissions etc.

As said in the beginning, I'm still investigating on this approach, its pros and cons, so any consideration about it is welcome.